# Is there additional overhead to run debian based docker container on centos?

Tags: docker

I could not find info by web search for `docker run debian based container on centos efficiency`. I've found cross-distro containerization works usually fine e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945109/what-will-be-impacted-for-compiling-code-in-different-kernel-in-docker, but not much on efficiency.

I would like to know what is (if any) additional overhead to run `debian` based docker container on `centos` and vice versa?

Comment: What kind of efficiency are you talking about?

Comment: @GregL, I mean CPU load, host memory footprint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of resource efficiency (CPU, RAM), the container's "distro" being different than the host's doesn't really have any effect on the efficiency, because you're not actually running a full distro inside the container.

The only aspect that might become inefficient when using containers with different distros is that you're likely to use more disk space on the host, as it has to store a wider variety of layers, some of which might only be used by a single image.

Ideally, each container only runs a single process, so the container's distro is more about the environment that surrounds that process (tooling, paths, command names, etc..).

Many Docker images, have a few "flavours" of image (differentiated by tags). One is generally based on CentOS, Debian, or Ubuntu, and another is generally based on Alpine.

[Nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) for example exists with the following tags (among others):

- `1.17.6`, `mainline`, `1`, `1.17`, `latest`
- `1.17.6-perl`, `mainline-perl`, `1-perl`, `1.17-perl`, `perl`
- `1.17.6-alpine`, `mainline-alpine`, `1-alpine`, `1.17-alpine`, `alpine`
- `1.17.6-alpine-perl`, `mainline-alpine-perl`, `1-alpine-perl`, `1.17-alpine-perl`, `alpine-perl`

The `1.17.6`, and `1.17.6-alpine` tagged images would contain the exact same Nginx binaries and configuration, but would differ in what tools are available to the container. If you were to load the same configuration file on both, they would consume the same amount of CPU/RAM for the same workload applied.

Comment: thank you. so like if I pull image based on debian on centos host it will download  additional layer(s) with debian commands etc as opposed to pulling it on debian host where these layers will be skipped? 
P.S. my current needed image has only one flavour and I wondered if I need to rebuild it myself to better suit target host - hence my original question.

Comment: No matter which host you're on, it will always pull the same layers for a given image/tag. That ensures consistency for the container, and is one of the core principles of why containerization is a thing.

Comment: Also, no, you don't need to rebuild your own image to match your host's distro. My advice is to use what's out there on DockerHub, and only build your own images when you need to.

Comment: a, so "using containers with different distros" you mean several containers having different distros one from another (not from the host)?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. If you're running a dozen containers, it's likely that you'll have a bunch of different base distros. Some Debian, some Ubuntu, some CentOS, some Alpine, and maybe (probably) even different versions of each distro. There's no overhead/downside to that, unless you're worried about disk space.